# Quickbooks ItemServiceQueryRq not returning all service items

Tags: quickbooks

I am implementing a billing system for a client. I wrote this XML query to grab all the Item Service Codes from the company file:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
<?qbxml version=\"2.0\"?>
<QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError=\"continueOnError\">
    <ItemServiceQueryRq  requestID=\"81\"></ItemServiceQueryRq>
  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

For the life of me I can't get QB web connector to return all of the service codes. The company file has about 500 service codes but it only returns 67. Does anyone have any idea on why this would happen? The QB web connector application log doesn't provide any hints either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you *sure* they are all service items? They aren't inventory or non-inventory items? Issue an ItemInventoryQuery, ItemNonInventoryQuery, or even a generic ItemQUery to get everything.

Duplicate question of [this question on the Intuit Developer Forums](https://idnforums.intuit.com/messageview.aspx?catid=56&threadid=15463). I answered your question on the Intuit forums... but you can mark my answer as correct here too. :-)

Comment: lol yes, thank you very much (actually I didn't check back on the Intuit site). But your suggestion worked, your help is greatly appreciated!